# Search on field collection with EntityFieldQuery

Tags: entities, database

I have a node resource with fields

> - name
> - files (field collection)

And field collection with fields

> - title
> - path

How can I search all node have file title = 'example'

How can I do it don't use view. Can we use EntityFieldQuery?

Comment: My sandbox should be helpful https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mikeytown2/2209909

Comment: Thanks. How can I install EntityFieldQueryExtra?